# How correctly cancel LoadAsync after some timeout

Tags: multithreading, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

Consider that I am using thread, which reads data stream from network socket (Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocket) with help of Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader (m_reader). I need to stop this thread and it waits mostly in LoadAsync. How to correctly cancel LoadAsync method after some timeout?

```
auto t1 = create_task(m_reader->LoadAsync(sizeof(len)));
t1.wait();
```

I tried several ways but none worked correctly. Or I can't use DataReader and I must choose some other approach?

Comment: Just close the socket.  Inevitably that must and will end LoadAsync() as well.  If the socket needs to survive for some reason then use CancelIOAsync().

Comment: I do it so now, but it throws some bloody exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x1242EB18. HRESULT:0x800703E3. I would like to know if there is a cleaner way without this exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call `t1.wait();` is a blocking call that will throw an exception if the `LoadAsync` call fails for some reason. In your case, that HRESULT is ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED, which is pretty much what I would expect ("The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.")

What you could do is create a task cancellation token, attach it to your task, and then fire the token cancellation when desired.

From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh780559:

```
//Class member:
cancellation_token_source m_fileTaskTokenSource;

// Cancel button event handler:
m_fileTaskTokenSource.cancel();

// task chain
auto getFileTask2 =
  create_task(documentsFolder->GetFileAsync(fileName), 
                                 m_fileTaskTokenSource.get_token());
```

Note: calling cancel on the cancellation token will cause the the task to throw a `task_canceled` exception, so you will need to catch and handle that exception.

Comment: Probably best solution yet, but after some tests sometimes it throws 0x800703E3 instead task_canceled :-/ So not fully reliable